# Doubts on classes when implementing binary search trees

Tags: c++, class, templates, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am studying generic binary search trees (BST) and AVL trees (AVL) on some notes that contain implementation pseudocodes. I am a bit puzzled about some details of their implementation.

The BST is based on the `struct Node` below

```
struct Node{
  int key;
  Node* parent;
  Node* left;
  Node* right;

  //constructors
}

//methods
```

The AVL version is basically the same with a few fields more for balancing the tree (I'll call it `AVLNode` for clarity, but there's no such distinction on the notes):

```
struct AVLNode{
  int key;
  int height;
  int size;
  AVLNode* parent;
  AVLNode* leftchild;
  AVLNode* rightchild;

  //constructors
}

//methods
```

A lot of operations are the same between the two trees and I can easily use templates in order to reuse them on both trees. However, consider the operation `insert`, which inserts a new node. The code for a BST is something like

```
//Insert node with key k in tree with root R
void insert(const int& k, Node* root){
  Node* N=find(k, root);         //finds where to insert the node
  if (N->key>k)
    N->leftchild=new Node(k,N);  //inserts as a left child
  else
    N->rightchild=new Node(k,N); //inserts as a right child
}
```

Now, the point is that the `insert` operation of an AVL tree is basically the same. The **pseudocode** presented in the notes is as follows:

```
void avlInsert(int k, AVLNode* R){
  insert(k,R);          //same operations as for Nodes, shown above
  AVLNode* N=find(x,R); //find node inserted (generic operation for BST)
  rebalance(N);         //perform balancing operations specific to AVL trees 
}
```

I'm a bit puzzled at this point, I know that the above is just a pseudocode but I was wondering whether there is a way to reuse the operation `insert` already provided for `Node`. Using template specialization would just mean writing a different specialization `insert<AVLNode>` for `AVLNode`, so that's not what I'm referring to.

I think a way would be to define `AVLNode` as a child class of `Node` and then use something like

```
struct AVLNode : Node {
  //implementation
}

void avlInsert(int k, AVLNode* R){
  Node *root=R;
  insert(k,root);
  AVLNode* N=find(x,R);
  rebalance(N);
}
```

but I'm not quite sure this would work and I don't know how to manage the pointers to `parent` and the childs (i.e. they must be pointers to `Node` inside `Node` and to `AVLNode` inside `AVLNode`).

Is there a way to avoid rewriting the same code?

Comment: Have you considered oop? Looks like AVL node is a special Node. You can have AVL node extend None and then use generic Node whereever possible

Comment: Yes, read the last paragraph.

Comment: The point is that there are 3 pointers `Node*` in `Node`, which must be `AVLNode*` in `AVLNode`. If I just redefine them in `AVLNode`, the child class will have three useless `Node*` pointers in `AVLNode`.

Comment: Can you show the `insert` code that you don't want repeated? I'm not clear on how much duplication there is. If the code is basically the same, you might be able to use templates.

Comment: Don't bother with inheritance or simplifying.  You will spend more effort than the benefits you receive.  Since the structures are independent, keep them that way.

Comment: @cigien I added the code for `insert`. It's not a big deal to repeat the code, it's just that `AVLNode` can be defined as a child to `Node`, and I was wondering whether this fact can be used to reuse the code for `insert`.
This also answers to @ThomasMatthews, I already implemented this with templates, was just wondering.

Comment: Different structure but same idea: Does this answer your question? [If 'A' has a member variable 'x' of type 'A\*', and 'B' inherits from 'A', how to redefine 'x' as 'B\*' inside of 'B'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244089/if-a-has-a-member-variable-x-of-type-a-and-b-inherits-from-a-how-to)

Comment: Thanks @HTNW, that partially answers my doubt on the pointer. I'll test it and eventually update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CRTP here. This would allow you to create the left right and parent nodes in the baseclass. For example consider something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct BaseNode{
  int key;
  T* parent;
  T* left;
  T* right;
};

struct AVLNode : public BaseNode<AVLNode>{
  int height;
  int size;
  AVLNode(const int&k, AVLNode*root){};
  AVLNode(){};
};
struct Node : public BaseNode<Node>{
    Node(const int&k, Node*root){};
    Node(){};
};

template<typename T>
T* find(const int& k, T* root){return root;};

template<typename T>
void insert(const int& k, T* root){
  T* N=find(k, root);         //finds where to insert the node
  if (N->key>k)
    N->left=new T(k,N);  //inserts as a left child
  else
    N->right=new T(k,N); //inserts as a right child
}

void test(){
    AVLNode avl_root;
    Node node_root;
    insert(42, &avl_root);
    insert(42, &node_root);
}
```

The downside is that the compiler will generate more code than necessary. Because it creates a new insert function for every type. This might not be a problem for you, but something worth considering. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hEY7eG) for the generated code.

As an aside. **Please please please please** don't use raw pointers and new and delete. You'll be going to get so many memory leaks, especially if a pointer gets "lost" because its parent gets deleted. Consider using smart pointers like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`